# The sentry alawys down at 9 p.m

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

After Capacity expansion, everyday, the sentry(sentry-1.5.1+cdh5.15.2+470) alawys down at 9 p.m, as flow:

```
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Iteration request failed : SELECT 'org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.model.MPath' AS NUCLEUS_TYPE,`A0`.`PATH_NAME`,`A0`.`PATH_ID`,`A0`.`AUTHZ_OBJ_ID` FROM `AUTHZ_PATH` `A0` WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.model.MAuthzPathsMapping' AS NUCLEUS_TYPE,`A0_SUB`.`AUTHZ_OBJ_ID` AS `DN_DATASTOREID` FROM `AUTHZ_PATHS_MAPPING` `A0_SUB` WHERE `A0_SUB`.`AUTHZ_SNAPSHOT_ID` = ? AND `A0`.`AUTHZ_OBJ_ID` = `A0_SUB`.`AUTHZ_OBJ_ID`)
NestedThrowables:
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:451)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:252)
    at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.persistent.SentryStore.retrieveFullPathsImageCore(SentryStore.java:2542)
    at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.persistent.SentryStore.access$2800(SentryStore.java:131)
    at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.persistent.SentryStore$39.execute(SentryStore.java:2518)
    at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.persistent.SentryStore$39.execute(SentryStore.java:2509)
    at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.persistent.TransactionManager.executeTransaction(TransactionManager.java:123)
    at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.persistent.SentryStore.retrieveFullPathsImageUpdate(SentryStore.java:2508)
    at org.apache.sentry.hdfs.PathImageRetriever.retrieveFullImage(PathImageRetriever.java:52)
    at org.apache.sentry.hdfs.PathImageRetriever.retrieveFullImage(PathImageRetriever.java:32)
    at org.apache.sentry.hdfs.DBUpdateForwarder.retrieveFullImage(DBUpdateForwarder.java:141)
    at org.apache.sentry.hdfs.DBUpdateForwarder.getAllUpdatesFrom(DBUpdateForwarder.java:92)
    at org.apache.sentry.hdfs.SentryPlugin.getAllPathsUpdatesFrom(SentryPlugin.java:163)
    at org.apache.sentry.hdfs.SentryHDFSServiceProcessor.getPathsUpdatesFrom(SentryHDFSServiceProcessor.java:130)
    at org.apache.sentry.hdfs.SentryHDFSServiceProcessor.get_authz_updates(SentryHDFSServiceProcessor.java:68)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2211)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. As it's currently written, it's unclear what your question is. If you do have one, please make it more explicit. You may also want to have a read through [ask] for guidance on writing your question.

Comment: You need to provide a little more detail. The error relates to this part of your SQL ````AUTHZ_SNAPSHOT_ID` = ?``` The ? is a placeholder for a value to be supplied when the query is being executed. The error means that the value that should be supplied for the ? was not supplied. But there is nothing here that gives a clue as to why. Please refer to Please refer to
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and
[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)